# How to set action mode over toolbar in android

Tags: android

I have created only tool bar in my fragment.I have implemented the action mode for multiple deleting the list view.But the action mode will open above the toolbar(i.e)action bar.How to display that action mode over the toolbar.I have tried `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` in my theme but it does not works.`

```
public class Event_notification extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener  {

    List<String> myList;
    private List<FeedItem> feedsList= new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    ListView listView;
    TextView emptyview;
    String message;
    EventNotification_adapter adapter;
    String userID,userid_share;
    CheckBox check;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String EventStatus,date;
    Dialog dialog;
    public static ActionMode mActionMode;
    ActionBar action;
    private JSONObject EventJsonObject;
    protected static final String TAG = "NOTIFICATION";
    ProgressWheel pw;
    ResetPasswordActivity obj = new ResetPasswordActivity();
    Constants constants=new Constants();

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public Event_notification() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *

     * @return A new instance of fragment Event_notification.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();


        SharedPreferences prefs1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        userID= prefs1.getString("userid", null);
        System.out.println("userid" + userID);

//        actionBar.hide();
        // setHasOptionsMenu(false);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        System.out.println("Notification Fragment");
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_notification, container, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_eventnotification, container, false);
        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getContext().getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) v);
        emptyview=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        check=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check1);
        pw = (ProgressWheel) v.findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
        obj.styleRandom(pw, getContext());
        getnotification();

        adapter=new EventNotification_adapter(getContext(),feedsList,Event_notification.this);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new  MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override

            public boolean  onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;

            }
                @Override

            public void  onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                adapter.removeSelection();
                               }
                      @Override

            public boolean  onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO  Auto-generated method stub
                mActionMode = mode;
            mActionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.multiple_delete, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean  onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode,

                                                final MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO  Auto-generated method stub
                    switch  (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.selectAll:
                            final int checkedCount  = feedsList.size();

                        // If item  is already selected or checked then remove or
                        // unchecked  and again select all
                            for (int i = 0; i < checkedCount; i++) {
                                listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                            //  listviewadapter.toggleSelection(i);
                        }
                            mode.setTitle(checkedCount  + "  Selected");
                             return true;

                    case R.id.unselect:
                        mode.finish();
                        return false;

                    case R.id.delete:

                        // Add  dialog for confirmation to delete selected item
                        // record.
                        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                        builder.setMessage("Do you  want to delete selected record(s)?");
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override

                            public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO  Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                        });

                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // TODO  Auto-generated method stub
                                   SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                                            .getSelectedIds();

                                    for (int i = (selected.size()); i >= 0; i--) {
                                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
//                                        String selecteditem=Integer.parseInt(selected.keyAt(i));
//
                                        FeedItem movie = feedsList.get(selected.keyAt(i));

                                        list.add(movie.getMessageid());

                                        System.out.println("EVENT ID____"+list);

                                        int  selecteditem = selected.keyAt(i);
                                        // String selecteditem1=Integer.toString(item.getItemId());
                                        int selecteditem1=item.getItemId();

                                        EventDelete();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        // Remove  selected items following the ids
                                            adapter.remove(selecteditem);
                                        System.out.println("FEEDLIST SIZE+++"+feedsList.size());
                                        if(feedsList.size()==0){
                                            emptyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            emptyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // Close CAB
                                mode.finish();
                                selected.clear();
                            }

                        });

                        AlertDialog alert =  builder.create();
                        //alert.setIcon(R.drawable.questionicon);// dialog  Icon
                        alert.setTitle("Confirmation"); // dialog  Title
                        alert.show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        mode.finish();
                        return false;

                }


            }
```

`

Comment: Where is the Toolbar in your code>

Comment: This is nested fragment so the toolbar is implemented in main fragment

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
android.view.ActionMode mMode = toolbar.startActionMode(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(
                    ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(
                    ActionMode mode) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(
                    ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(
                    ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    return false;
            }
});
```

if you want to **Fininsh** Action mode

```
if (mMode != null) {
        mMode.finish();
}
```

And don't forget to add following in your main Theme under `styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

You are good to go.

Comment: where i have to put this coding inside the listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener or else outside

Comment: you are using ActionMode of muliple choice.. ohhh. okey.. just add `<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` in your main Theme under `styles.xml` forget about the rest

Comment: Any one answer me soon if knows

Comment: @sri use this if using api < 21 in style `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`